# How do I use a function with valueFormatter if the colDef is preDefined and in quotes? - AG-Grid

Tags: angular, typescript, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

If I have json data that predefines my columnDefs and want to use valueFormatters as a function but the value formatter in the json reads valueFormatter: "dateFormatter" instead of valueFormatter: dateFormatter. How would I go about accessing a function

The way the json is written is : (valueFormatter: "dateFormatter")
but in order for me to use valueFormater as a function I need : (valueFormatter: dateFormatter)

Answer (score 0):

A better way of doing this would be to leverage [Custom Column Types](https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-grid/column-definitions/#default-column-definitions).

In your JSON, just add the `type` property on a column:

```
{field:"athlete", type:"athleteType"}
```

Then bind the `[columnTypes]` Grid property:

```
<ag-grid-angular
    [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
    [columnTypes]="columnTypes"
    /* other grid options ... */>
</ag-grid-angular>
```

Now inside the `columnTypes` you can define your `valueFormatter` function:

```
// define a column type (you can define as many as you like)
this.columnTypes = {
    athleteType: { valueFormatter: params => 'athlete' },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you did want to do it with a String then the grid would initially render incorrectly because the grid would make an attempt to format with the String.

So fairly quickly after setting it up you would need to update the `columnDefs`

You would have to 'find the function' then amend the `columnDef` to have valueFormatter point to the function, then `setColumnDefs` and `refreshRows` to re-build the DOM to have the function allocated.

e.g.

```
    // get the current column definitions
    var columnDefs = gridOptions.api.getColumnDefs();

    // loop over them all
    columnDefs.forEach(colDef =>{
        // if it has a valueFormatter
        if(colDef.valueFormatter){
          // and it is a string
          if(typeof colDef.valueFormatter == "string"){
            // if we can find the function
            if(window[colDef.valueFormatter] 
               && typeof window[colDef.valueFormatter]=="function"){
                  // assign the function as the valueFormatter
                  colDef.valueFormatter = window[colDef.valueFormatter];
            }
          }
        }
      });

    // reconfigure the grid with the new definitions
    gridOptions.api.setColumnDefs(columnDefs);

    // force a redraw so that the function can take effect
    gridOptions.api.redrawRows();
```